# Can a software development lifecycle be iterative without being incremental?

Tags: development-process, sdlc, iterative-development

Do any lifecycle models exist that are iterative without incremental? Is this even possible?

Comment: What's the distinction between iterative and incremental to you, and why does it matter?

Comment: FWIW, "iterative without incremental" would mean to develop every new version of a piece software from scratch. Might be of use in some learning or academic context, but the practical relevance is IMHO zero.

Comment: Can those who down vote this question tell us why ?

Comment: @quintumnia: the tool tip at the "downvote" button starts with "This question does not show any research effort" - seems to be a valid reason for downvoting this post. Maybe I should downvote, too, still considering.

Comment: @DocBrown if the question doesn't show any research effort,then why do we have answers upvoted for!....Why do they answer the question that lacks or shows no research effort.Be fair humans!

Comment: @quintumnia: you have to ask the answerers, not me. But Ewan's answer also shows the question is quite unclear, for me it looks he interpreted in a different way than I interpret the question. Ok, you convinced me, I give it a downvote, too, the question does not only show no research effort, it is also so unclear it deserves a downvote. I may remove the downvote and maybe cast a reopen vote when the OP edits the question and reacts to  the first comment above.

Comment: @DocBrown  That's why I always say,human beings is a young species and deserves much to learn in this universe.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can exist. It would mean that you build the whole product from start to finish, then throw it all away and start all the way from the beginning.

This *is* actually sometimes practiced during the prototyping phase, but usually not for the *actual* product.

I guess it is more common in research than in commercial development. E.g. MIT used to develop a new AI language from scratch every couple of years (PLANNER, CONNIVER, PLASMA, Scheme). Smalltalk-71, Smalltalk-72, and Smalltalk-74 didn't have very much in common, and in fact Alan Kay proposed to "burn the disk packs", i.e. abandon the Smalltalk project completely and start from scratch, because he felt that the evolution of Smalltalk was moving away from his vision of OO.

However, it is more common as a one-off event to get a derailed project back on track.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Agile methodologies tout the idea of iterative development over additive. The idea being that you constantly improve the same functionality rather than adding more features.

Obviously that doesn't mean you program the whole thing on day 1 or never add a new feature.

It's a reaction against a common pattern businesses fall into where they constantly add more features into a backlog and measure success by how many they can add.

This leads to big complicated systems which often don't do their core thing particularly well.

Comment: "Agile methodologies tout the idea of iterative development over additive." -- All of the major agile methodologies are iterative and incremental.

Comment: What you say is *"in any iterative & incremental model, there can be sometimes pure iterative cycles"*. That does not make the whole lifecycle model purely iterative.

Comment: I think these methodologies _claim_ to be incremental. But they claim to be a lot of things.